# storing sources and build files in git

Tags: git, github

I'm working on some library which I want to share through github. I have watch gulp task that concatenate all my library *.js files into one and put it in `build` folder each time I made a change somewhere in sources. So currently in repository I have both sources and concatenated file. The problem with my current approach is that each time commit made it can be seen twice in history - as change somewhere in source files and as change in build file. What are the best way of handling such libraries in git repositories?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you handle compiled files from pre-processors in git commits?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17970130/how-do-you-handle-compiled-files-from-pre-processors-in-git-commits)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend removing the concatenated javascript file from the git repository using `git rm {file.js}` and then add that file to `.gitignore`  From then on, you should only commit the changes to the files that you actually touched, and don't track the autogenerated files in git anymore.

Comment: but then, any one who ever would like to use my library, should go through building process which may became tricky in future

Comment: In general, I disagree with tracking autogenerated files.  You should have a `README` file that explains how to build your repository.  Usually, developers use a `Makefile` and all a user needs to do is run `make` ... In general, any user that downloads a source code repository must build it in order to use the product, so causing the user to do this should not be unexpected.

Comment: I'm close to agree with you but somehow libraries like [threejs](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/) contain builds in their repositories without having to track all they commits history

Comment: as shown here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/commits/master/build commits to the generated `build/*.js` files are usually committed in a separate step from the actual source file commits.  All the history is indeed tracked.